# Unsemantic CSS Framework, wrapping li's

Tags: css, responsive-design, html-lists, word-wrap, unsemantic-css

I'm using unsemantic as a responsive framework. I've got some li's in a footer menu that fit perfectly on one line, on the desktop version.

For some strange reason, when I resize my browser, so that it shows the mobile version - and then resize again so that I view the desktop version - the ul at the bottom, has some li's that are wrapping.

Menu HTML

```
<nav id="the-footer-menu">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="about">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="philosophy">Philosophy</a></li>
  <li><a href="services">Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="testimonials">Testimonials</a></li>
  <li><a href="home">FAQs</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

Desktop CSS

```
#the-footer-menu ul li {
font-size: 13px;
padding: 0 10px;
border-right: 1px solid #fff;
float: left;
}
```

Mobile CSS

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px){
 #the-footer-menu ul{text-align: center;}
 #the-footer-menu ul li{display: inline-block;float: none;}
}
```

Comment: If you don't give, code, fiddle, or example page it's going to be very hard to answer

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I put "display:inline-block" for the li and "white-space:nowrap" on the parent ul. I did this via developer tools. When I resize again though, the li's wrap. It's such a shame, because this framework works perfectly other than this.